# Why am I getting a temporary 403 Forbidden Error when accessing session protected pages on my web application?

Tags: php, session, dashboard, http-status-code-403

Im building a web application using php backend (no frameworks, custom code), with a user dashboard section protected by a session variable which is initialized at the time the user logins to his/her account. All dashboard pages check to see if the session variable is set and is == true. If not, the page redirects to the login page. Basic.

This all works fine on localhost but on the live site the following error appears when a logged in user attempts to navigate to another session-protected page:

Forbidden
You don't have permission to access this resource.

Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

However, when you wait a few seconds and refresh the page, the intended page opens normally.

Is anyone familiar with such a problem and can anyone help solve this? Thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.